# Can't convert text type value into True/False in Power BI using DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have an column called ProyectoID that holds unique records. This column is type text. The error says: "Can't convert "Talbot" of type Text into type True/False"
This is wierd considering that before Talbot was added, it worked perfectly.

[image]

Comment: Why are you passing that column as a filter expression to `CALCULATE`? What are your expected results for the first few rows of that table?

Comment: Hello @JosWoolley. What I am trying to do here is to sum all the values from the table 'Proyectos' that have the same ProyectoID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generalized solution for a Calculated Column would be:

```
=
VAR ThisID = 'Table'[ID]
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Table'[Value] ),
        FILTER (
            'Table',
            'Table'[ID] = ThisID
        )
    )
```